# How to replace a receptacle with four hot and four neutral wires?

Tags: receptacle

I am replacing some receptacles in my Master Bedroom. I have replaced 7 so far and they all have the same setup: 4 wires and 1 ground. They are straight forward to replace.

When I opened the last receptacle, I found out that it had 9 wires: 8 wires and 1 ground (see attached picture)I couldn't understand how this work and how I could replace it and closed it back. That receptacle is not connected to any switch.

Why do I have 9 wires for that receptacle? How can I replace it?

[image]

Comment: Is it a split circuit? (Are the tabs on the side of the outlet twisted off?)

Comment: Good question. I will have to open the receptacle again to figure that out. Why would this be on a split circuit? The house was built in 2007.

Comment: @Martin Split circuits are either for separate control of receptacles (e.g. switched), or to provision them to separate circuits or breakers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that they aren't a split circuit, just bundle them all by color and add a pigtail to each bundle for the outlet. You'll need red wire nuts to handle that many wires, assuming #14. Some brands will accept five #12. Make sure you do a clean job of combining and twisting the bundle to ensure good contact.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @isherwood! Why this would not have been done by the electrician who wired the house back in 2007?

Comment: Because (s)he had an outlet with all those nifty connectors. That's not a common style, but I can see where it would come in handy. Some of our resident pros consider them poor quality connections, though. Pigtailing is more reliable.

Comment: If you get a "back and side" outlet they are a bit more expensive but the 2 screws on each side will securely clamp 2 wires under each screw, I use these if the box is tight and there is not enough room to pig tail.

Comment: Ed means a screw-and-clamp type outlet, like Leviton's $3 receptacles.   Note that all the current connections are backstabs, which are not reliable.   If you want to use those, add an AFCI breaker.  @martin they probably chose that specific receptacle model because it had all those splice points... in residential construction, **time *is* money** and they use wiring methods that are fastest, such as backstabs.

Comment: [More on screw-and-clamp vs backstabs](https://www.handymanhowto.com/electrical-outlets-side-wire-versus-back-wire/).

Answer (score 1):

### It's not just a receptacle.  It's a combo device.

It's a receptacle. *And it's a splice block too*.

Receptacles are rather clever devices.  They need two screws for other reasons (breaking off tabs for separate control).  But if you don't break off tabs, they also double as **splice blocks for multiple taps**.  Most 2-screw receptacles allow you to attach three things, so it's the equivalent of two 3-terminal splice bars:

- One hot-neutral pair (presumably the supply wires)
- Another hot-neutral pair (presumably, more downstream outlets)
- the receptacle itself

Some receptacles are built with 4 attachment points per side, making it the equivalent of two *five-terminal* splice bars.

That is exactly what's happening here.  Supply is being branched off to other locations for other purposes.

Comment: Wow. That's interesting. So do I need a special receptacle to replace this one or any will do?

Comment: @Martin You can either use a [receptacle equipped to accommodate four wires](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-ProGrade-15-Amp-Commercial-Duplex-Outlet-White-BR15-W/100662483), or you can use an external splice device equipped to accommodate five, and pigtail the receptacle.  *You **must** do the latter with the ground wires, regardless.*

Comment: Thank you for the link @Harper. It looks like I am not going to be able to use the Lutron SCRS-15-TR-SW receptacle... :(

Comment: @Martin Why would you want to?  It's stupid overpriced.  White Decora receptacles are a commodity item that everyone makes and you should find an intersection with the Leviton ProGrade line or competitors who also offer screw-and-clamp.   If you just can't use any of them, try "lever-nuts", they make them in 5's... or pigtail them *carefully* under an [Ideal brand](http://www.electriciantalk.com/f14/wire-nuts-what-best-2084/) wirenut, red or large tan.  This is really maxing out a wirenut, so don't mess with non-Ideal brands and check  your work carefully.

Comment: I agree Lutron is way over-priced. I wanted all the screw less wall plates, dimmers and receptacles to match color and style. I couldn't get a perfect match with Leviton. Only Lutron was able to give me the same style/color.